# List of all homebrew package names (not a count)

Tags: homebrew

Is it possible to get a complete list of all homebrew package names that are able to install using `brew install PACKAGE_NAME`? (not just a count of all packages)

There is a complete list of available Homebrew packages [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/), but I would like a script if available

Comment: @Nimesh Neema I don't think that this question is a duplicate, because I don't just want a complete count, I want a list of all the packages

Comment: The linked question contains the answer, **`brew search`**, with the count only from a locally piping into `wc -l`. Do you think this needs to be clarified in the linked question?

Comment: I think so, at least I didn't know that it did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `brew search` to get a complete list of all available packages.
[This](http://searchbrew.com/) website provides a great search functionality to search in all the packages

Comment: This is a link only answer that is subject to link rot...

Comment: Hi - consider editing this in to the answer in the linked question. No need to delete anything here. Closed questions help with search engines to find the main Q/A for one topic so having several linked and closed questions helps the site and isn’t any penalty for you.

Comment: @SolarMike While I would agree in most cases, I disagree here for two reasons.  1. There's no point in copying and pasting everything on that link because it's way too long 2. It's subject to change on the daily, and therefore would be outdated pretty quickly.

Comment: @Josh perhaps a script that would download the latest list to the desktop would be more relevant...